# Serialize Haystack SearchQuerySet

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have some Django queries dumped in files that are delayed so I pass as parameter `sql_with_params` to later execute in the delayed a `raw` query.

I have migrated all queries to haystack so I wan't to do the same with `SearchQuerySet`.

Is there any way to get the raw_query of an already constructed SearchQuerySet?

PD: I am using ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, here's one way that unfortunately requires a bit of plumbing. You can create a custom search engine and set its query to your own query definition inheriting from `ElasticsearchSearchQuery`:

```
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import ElasticsearchSearchEngine, ElasticsearchSearchQuery


class ExtendedElasticsearchSearchQuery(ElasticsearchSearchQuery):
    def build_query(self):
        raw_query = super(ExtendedElasticsearchSearchQuery, self).build_query()
        # TODO: Do something with raw query
        return raw_query

class ExtendedElasticsearchSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
    query = ExtendedElasticsearchSearchQuery
```

and reference that from your settings:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'myapp.mymodule.ExtendedElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack'
    },
}
```